# Splitting file in scala

Tags: scala

I want to iterate over a file in scala and split it into 10 000 lines smaller files. How can I do this?

```
def splitFile(file: String, num: Int): Boolean = {
    val buffer = "";
    Source
        .fromFile(file)
        .getLines
        .foreach((line: String, i: Int) => {
            buffer = buffer + line;
            if (i % num == 0) {
                println(i);
            }
        });
};
```

Right now I have something like this, but - `foreach` loop doesn't have an iterator. Also, I can't iterate variables in scala - `cannot reassign variable`, `not an Int type`, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a huuuuuuugggggeeee file. What is the approximate size of file that you are working with ?

Answer (score 2):

On a *NIX system that has the `split` binary:

```
import sys.process._
s"split -l 10000 $filename" !
```

Comment: This is operating system dependent. A ```split``` binary with exactly those parameters must be installed.

Comment: That's true, but a pure scala solution is already provided (or in the process of being provided) by another user, and I thought it's always interesting to provide another take on an otherwise pretty straightforward problem. 

It could help the OP, and also help anyone for which the system condition isn't a problem (it's not like it's drastic either, split is commonly available).

Answer (score 1):

If your file just huge (~500 MB) and not huge-huge (~ 5 GB's). You can use the following function.

```
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter}
import scala.io.Source

def breakFileInPartsOfSizeN(filePath: String, n: Int): Unit = {

  val fileSource = Source.fromFile(filePath)
  val fileSourceLineIterator = fileSource.getLines()

  def getNextBufferedFileWriter(i: Int) = {
    val nextFilePath = filePath + ".part_" + i
    val nextFile = new File(nextFilePath)
    val bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nextFile))
    bfw
  }

  def writeNextNLines(
    i: Int,
    n: Int,
    remaining: Int,
    lineIterator: Iterator[String],
    bufferedFileWriterOption: Option[BufferedWriter] = None
  ): Unit = {
    assert(n >= 0)

    val bufferedFileWriter = (remaining, bufferedFileWriterOption) match {
      case (0, None) => getNextBufferedFileWriter(i + 1)
      case (0, Some(bfw)) =>
        bfw.close()
        getNextBufferedFileWriter(i + 1)
      case (_, None) =>
        getNextBufferedFileWriter(i)
      case (_, Some(bfw)) => bfw
    }

    if (remaining == 0) {
      writeNextNLines(i + 1, n, n, lineIterator, Some(bufferedFileWriter))
    }
    else if (lineIterator.hasNext) {
      val line = lineIterator.next()
      bufferedFileWriter.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"))
      writeNextNLines(i, n, remaining - 1, lineIterator, Some(bufferedFileWriter))
    }
    else {
      bufferedFileWriter.close()
      // Well... we are done...
    }
  }

  writeNextNLines(0, n, n, fileSourceLineIterator)

}
```

Now... you can use it like this

```
breakFileInPartsOfSizeN("/your/file/absolute/path/filename.txt", 10000)
```

It will create part files with names `/your/file/absolute/path/filename.txt.part_n`

Comment: Any suggestions for what I can do if my file is huge-huge (200GB)?

Comment: The this program will take hours to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if you want to mutate a variable, use `var` instead of `val`. `var` is the mutable option of `val`
Secondly, your foreach seems wrong.  Check the following code:

```
Source
  .fromFile(file)
  .getLines
  .foreach { line =>
    buffer = buffer + line
  }
```

I am not quite sure of the line number you want, but the following should work to get a list of number of lines defined by `num`

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(file).getLines.toList
lines.grouped(num).toList
```

Comment: calling `getLines` on a "huge" file is not a good idea. And then `toList` makes it even worse. And that `grouped` willl be the final nail in the coffin.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I agree, I didn't think of performance for this solution.  It's just something that works.

Comment: I agree that materializing with `toList` is bad, but why is `getLines` a bad idea? Since the result is an iterator I expect the input to be loaded one line at a time. Also `grouped` emits an iterator as well, so I would expect that just by removing the `toList` yo can work on a streaming data set and have constant memory occupation.

Comment: @stefanobaghino Even my solution is calling `getLines`. Its just the habit of people using a collector consumer after `getLines` is more problematic. As of why `getLines` is not a good idea is because it is not reliable if the file potentially originates from a different operating-system. I initially wanted to write that and had edited the comment. But somehow it was not saved at that time. And now it has already been > 5 minutes.

Comment: And... things will get better if we remove that `toList`. But even than `grouped(num: Int)` uses in-memory array buffer of size `num` which will have a significant memory footprint for ~10000 lines, which can be totally avoided.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `getLines`. The OP uses it, we can assume the line endings are handled correctly in their context. And there's no need for the `.toList`, iterators support `grouped`. `buffer` should be a StringBuilder, though, probably

Answer (score 0):

```
val step = 10000        
Source.fromFile(file).getLines
  .sliding(step, step)
  .zipWithIndex
  .foreach { case (seq, i) =>
     import java.io._
     val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("filename" + i))
     seq.foreach(pw.println)
     pw.close
   }
```